# nvd3.js will not take data from jquery

Tags: jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I do have some problems using the nvd3.js library to make a `stackedAreaChart` with data fetched from a webservice using jQuerys `$.getJSON` function, or the `d3.json` function.
I am getting the data from the webservice, but cant get the data into the chart.
I have tried with static data, and this works, but the truble starts when using `$.getJSON` or `d3.json`.

What am I doing wrong? And do you have any better ways of doing this?
Are there any better frameworks for making graphics (to show trends of data)?
Cant find any good resources on this, so thanks for any help! :)

```
<script>
var chart;
var data = [{
    "key": "HTTP 200",
    "values": getData()
}];
setupGraph();

    function setupGraph() {

        nv.addGraph(function() {

            chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                    .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
                    .y(function(d) { return d[1]/100 })
                    .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
                    .clipEdge(false);

            chart.xAxis
                .tickFormat(function(d) {
                    return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d))
                });

            chart.yAxis
                .tickFormat(d3.format(',1f'));

            d3.select('#chart1 svg')
                .datum(data)
                .transition().duration(500)
                .call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
            return chart;
        });
    }
function getData(){
    var arr = [];
    d3.json('http://localhost:8080/api', function(inndata){
        for(var i in inndata){
            var dataarr = new Array();
            dataarr[0] = new Date(inndata[i].date);
            dataarr[1] = inndata[i].count;
            arr.push(dataarr);
            //arr.push({x: new Date(inndata[i].date), y: inndata[i].count});
        }

    return arr;
}
</script>

The json string lookis like this:
[{"date": "2013-01-07 09:01", "count": 2}, {"date": "2013-01-07 05:02", "count": 2}, }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous - so you have to supply the setupGraph() within the callback to the d3.json method. So do something like this:

```
var arr = [];
d3.json('http://localhost:8080/api', function(inndata){
    for(var i in inndata){
        var dataarr = new Array();
        dataarr[0] = new Date(inndata[i].date);
        dataarr[1] = inndata[i].count;
        arr.push(dataarr);
        //arr.push({x: new Date(inndata[i].date), y: inndata[i].count});
    }
    var data = [{
       "key": "HTTP 200",
       "values": arr
    }];
    setupGraph(data) // Pass through data to setupGraph
}
```